# Problem with merged lines while extracting text from PDF using PDFBox 2.x

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have problem with extracting text from PDF using `PDFTextStripper` from `PDFBox 2.0.13`. To be more specific - lines, which are too close to each other, are merged together. For example:
[image]

On the first line, there is text "*signfieldbig*", the second line contains underscores but `PDFTextStripper` parsed it as "*s_i_g_n_fi_e_ld_b_ig_ _______*" (it merged both lines into one). I tried multiple settings (different lineSeparator, tresholds, etc..) but nothing helped. These two lines were merged every time and I cannot simply remove all unnecessary characters from text, because I am looking for position of this placeholder to create signature field.

UPDATE: I just realized what caused this problem - in original file aren't two normal lines separated by line separator but one line with underscores and manually placed text area with text "*placeholder*" above that. But still, PDF viewer (viewing it as text) or other PDF library (iText 2.x) parse it as two separate lines...

Comment: for fields you should use AcroForm. then place holder would not matter.

Comment: Indeed, if there are the underscores, after all, it is correct that they are extracted, and if the text effectively is at the same height as the underscore, it clearly can happen that they become mixed up.

Comment: @logger: I am not the creator of PDF file, therefore I need placeholder to know, where to place the field :)

Comment: @mkl The problem is that `PDFTextStripper ` is ignoring new line separator. In original Word file, there is new line separator (meaning there are two lines of text), in converted PDF file are two lines of text, viewing PDF in text viewer shows two lines, even parsing PDF file with another PDF library (old iText 2.x) shows 2 lines... only PDFBox is merging them together. Why it is ignoring new line separator and works as OCR?

Comment: That new line separator is *not* in the pdf. A pdf essentially contains instructions like "draw [a text chunk] at [coordinates]". If the y coordinates of different chunks are near enough to each other, text extractors may consider them to be on the same line; but different text extractors differ in their notion of "near enough". Using `setSortByPosition(false)` with the text stripper might help you.

Comment: @mkl You are the boss!! Yes, that helped. Thank You! Post a short response so I can check it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different strategies to text extraction, one can either take the text chunks as they come and only add a new line or something similar when the new next chunk's coordinates are not right after the previous one, or one can collect all chunks, sort them by coordinates, and extract the text from these sorted chunks.

(Obviously both strategy types can be combined with a certain degree of analysis of text layout.)

In your case sorting is active, causing the underscores and the text above to be joined as "s_i_g_n_fi_e_ld_b_ig_ _______".

You can disable sorting in the pdfbox text stripper using `setSortByPosition(false)`.

---

There is no universal best approach, depending on the document in question one or the other might be better.